# Merge sitecore project with another .net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore

I have a unique requirement which I need to meet to with sitecore, and I was wondering if it is feasible. The client has an existing .net solution, which is a web project (web site, not web application) that is built on the spring framework and commerce server. They now want to use sitecore to enable content editing on 'some' of their pages. THe requirement is that they do not want to maintain the master pages and any common items in sitecore, but they want sitecore to be able to use the master pages and all the controls they have in their custom solution. I've checked through their project, and they have a LOT of dependencies on many other references and projects, and so it is not a fairly simple application. They do not want to have the master pages specifically in sitecore, and they only want sitecore for the main content editing. They basically want all the layouts in sitecore to use their master pages. I've tried using virtual directories and then using the master pages in sitecore, but there are way too many dependencies in their project. I've tried to make sitecore an application within its own directory, but it doesn't seem to work very well. I can merge the web.configs as much as I can, but that is going to cause headaches down the road when its time to upgrade...My more high level question is, is this doable at all, and if there is a way I can meet this requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial thoughts are that using master pages within Sitecore is bit of a non-starter. It seems odd to have such requirements and have Sitecore already prescribed.

Three ideas come to mind.

1) Consider keeping the solutions separate, and host certain Sitecore pages in a clean, standard, Sitecore solution. Use a load balancer to direct which urls point where. There could be many side effects to this approach to do with sessions etc.

2) Migrate the existing solution to Sitecore replacing master pages with Sitecore layouts and sublayouts. At the same time, migrate to a web application project. This is very likely the best long term approach. The main challenge would be mapping existing content to a set of templates in Sitecore, and various bits of refactoring.

3) Use Sitecore as a content repository, but serve content from your existing web site solution. This will have numerous complicating factors due to lack of a typical Sitecore item, site & domain context which would all need to be handled by custom code. The solutions could be entirely separate, and even use web services to retrieve content from Sitecore which is served by the existing solution. It gives full separation, but you loose a large chunk of Sitecore functionality and end up with an expensive rich text editor + database.

I'd opt for #2 where possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can see a few options on how to do this. I'm currently doing something similar right now on a large enterprise project where there's an existing ASP.NET MVC application running the bulk of the site. Here are some options I can think of:

1. Use a sub-domain for the Sitecore-only stuff and `<iframe>` in the Sitecore content or do an HTTP GET to the Sitecore pages and pull the content into the existing app. E.g. `sc.mysite.com` is the Sitecore app. I'm currently doing this with MVC now and its fine. From a content management POV, editors can still use Page Edit mode on the Sitecore pages in their stand-alone state but the content is in production in the fed in state on the main MVC site.
2. Sitecore can use MasterPages, it just defeats the purpose of the presentation layer of Sitecore. Essentially, you can have your Sitecore layout inherit from the MasterPage and it works just like any normal application would with inheritance. I'm not sure of the caching implications though. As long as your app references the Sitecore assemblies, you can use the API as long as its part of the Sitecore context. If you DO use MasterPages with Sitecore, make sure you add a placeholder with the key **webedit** to allow page editor to work: `<sc:placeholder key="webedit" runat="server" />`